# Метрики кода

Tags: c, метрики, c++

Чем сосчитать количество чистых строк c/c++ кода (sloc) на убунте? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всего строк в файле:

cat source.cpp | wc -l

Если не считать однострочные комментарии(с соответствующими ограничениями)), то можно так:

cat source.cpp | grep -v "//" | wc -l

Если еще плюс к тому не считать пустые строки, то получим:

cat source.cpp | grep -v "//\|^[ ]*$"  | wc -l

Answer (score 1):

В Code::Blocks есть плагин Code Statistics, который всё это считает. =)

Comment: Автор вопроса хотел узнать, как посчитать в убунте, уж не знаю зачем). Вообще, такие вещи удобней считать в каких-нить тулах, которые ближе к мэнеджменту, типа jira, например. Еще людей могут интересовать, как эти самые строки кода связаны с выпуском версий, тогда svn+jira(fisheye).

Comment: А зачем нужно считать строки кода? Так ради интереса?

Comment: Вот зачем автору понадобилось считать строки кода именно в убунте я не знаю). А вообще тут тема такая: трудозатраты можно посчитать в человеко-днях(баксы), а произведенный за эти человеко-дни результат тоже хочется посчитать, для этого берут метрики (типа SLOC) и меряют продукт, не обязательно только код. Потом кумулятивную метрику продукта можно поделить на человеко-дни и сделать далеко идущие выводы об этих самых человеках)). Ну менеджерам тоже надо свой хлеб отрабатывать)).

Comment: А если человек взял, исправил чужой код, это тоже ведь надо посчитать за строки кода. :-D Есть какие-нибудь такие хитрые средства?)

Comment: svn. Надо считать количество срок измененного(svn diff) кода за коммит.

Comment: Чет не помню команд в subversion для таких расчетов. А вообще интересная тема, не подскажите, где можно почитать?)

Comment: Надо считать количество срок измененного(svn diff) кода за коммит (или за интересующий диапазон ревизий).

Comment: @psyhitus Правильнее создать новый вопрос.

Comment: Тут вот красивых графичков много.

http://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye/tour/code-analysis.jsp