# Подсчет метрик кода VC++

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, метрики, c++, visual-c++

Нужно посчитать метрики моего кода в Visual Studio 2010 (какие только можно) и метрики Холстеда (как угодно).

Это ответ VS 2010 на "Анализ->Рассчитать метрики кода для projectname": в целевом файле проекта "project\adress\Debug\projectname.exe" нет управляемого кода.

Программа есть, а скрипта нет=)? Что не так делаю?

- [Free C# metrics calculation library (DLL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052269/free-c-sharp-metrics-calculation-library-dll). Это вроде не то, хотя знанием английского похвастаться [пока=)] не могу.
- [Метрики программного обеспечения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1304/). Здесь только про деньги.
- [Метрики кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1285/) Тут про убунту, а мне надо в VS.

Comment: `Visual Studio 2010` не поддерживает метрики кода для `unmanaged` проектов. Можете воспользоваться, например, утилитой [**SourceMonitor.**][1]

[1]: http://www.campwoodsw.com/

Comment: Спасибо!
Эта штука вроде все считает, но не видит ни одной функции в моем коде=)